# What is the Correct Django Model Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, relational-database

Im a beginner in django and its modeling structure. And i would like to seek answer from anyone.

I have a model `Animal` and `Herd`

Each herd has a multiple animals and an animal belongs to a herd. So i design this many-to-one model relationship as an example. Am i in a wrong way or should i continue this practice? Because i am confuse with the [djangorestframework serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) of `Album` and `Track` model relationship. Please help.

**animal.models.py**

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    birth_weight = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sibling_order = models.IntegerField()
```

**herd.models.py**

```
class Herd(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKeyField(Animal, related_name="animals", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way round. You have a herd consisting of a single animal, but an animal belonging to many herds. You need to have the ForeignKey in Animal, pointing to Herd.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how can we explain the Album and Track relations in djangorestframework example? i was really confuse. because Album may have a ForeignKey in it but in the Track. very confusing.

Comment: I don't understand what you're confused about. An Album has many Tracks, just as a Herd has many Animals.

Comment: but the ForeignKey was in the Track not in the Album.

Comment: Yes. And here your ForeignKey must be in Animal.

Comment: me <- face-slap

Comment: Thanks for enlightening sir